# Laravel blade @includeWhen(request()->is('/contact'),'partials.jumbotron') not working

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, master-pages, laravel-blade

I want to use jumbotron section only my contact file. That's why i write this directive and code working and no error.

`@includeWhen(request()->is('/contact'),'jumbotron')`

Is above code format is right? if not

help me experts.

Comment: remove `/` in `request()->is('/contact')`

Answer (score 0):

please remove `/` in `request()->is('/contact')`